# multithread boost C++ program design for low-latency large-data exchange

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread, low-latency

I am trying to solve a network flow problem by C++ multithreading.

Given a network (all nodes are connected by arcs, each arc is connected to 2 and only 2 ending nodes, one is input node and another is output node, each node can have multiple input arcs and output arcs), each node needs to do some computing and then exchange 
computing result data to its connected input and output nodes.

Multiple nodes can be grouped into one task, which is run by one thread. In this way, the 
whole network computing workload can be partitioned into multiple tasks. All these tasks 
are pushed into a boost thread pool such that all threads can run the tasks at the same 
time.

But, if a node (in a thread task) needs to do data exchange with another node (in another 
thread task), there is a synchronization problem. Data receiver needs to wait for data 
available in the data buffer of the data sender.

My proram needs to partition the network such that each thread's task workload is assigned 
as evenly as possible.
If all threads share the one-large data buffer structure, the program parallelism is not 
good because the critical section is too large. Some threads have to wait the the 
one-large data buffer structure unlocked even though the part of the data structure (which 
is useful to them ) has been available for read or write.

For example, the one-large data buffer structure has the following buffer cells: 
cell1 , cell2,  cell3 , cell4.

When thread 1 is trying to write cell 1, it must lock the whole  data buffer structure so 
that thread 2 cannot read or write cell 2 and so on.

So, I want to break the one-large data buffer structure into multiple distinct data cells 
according to the thread number so that each cell holds the data only needed by one thread 
task.

For example, if we have 2 threads, we create 2 data cells that hold data needed by the 4 
thread separately. 
If we have 4 threads, we create 4 data cells that hold data needed by the 4 thread separately. 
and so on.

My questions are:

(1) How to design the data cell ? You can see that its size is based on the number of threads.

(2) How to reduce synchronization overhead ? The critical section is small but the 
overhead of geting and releasing mutex may be very high if the inter-node data exchange frequency is high.

(3) When a node's computing is done and data is written to its cell how to notify the data 
receiver node such that the notification messgae is only received by the waiting thread 
that run the receiver node computing task. All other unrelated nodes and threads are not 
impacted.

The program is very time-sensitive and the latency of message exchange should be 
controlled very toughly and reduced as much as possible.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of dealing with this, I think, is to set up a message-passing infrastructure between *threads*.

Each thread has a message queue.  In your example, say node N1 is assigned to thread 1, node N2 is assigned to thread 2, and there is an edge between N1 and N2.  Then, when thread 1 finishes the N1 calculation, it sends a message to thread 2:

"Send input  to node N2"

To send a message to a thread, you just lock that thread's message queue and append your message.  You use one mutex and two condition variables (queue_not_empty_condition and queue_not_full_condition) to implement a bounded queue.  When a thread wants to wait for new work, it just goes to sleep on its message queue.

To reduce the synchronization overhead, you might want a way to put multiple messages into a queue ("batch send") while locking the mutex just once.  Then then loop within one thread would look something like this:

```
if (I can do work without communicating with other threads)
    do that work
else
    send all pending messages (in batches to each destination thread)
    wait on my input queue and pop the messages off in a batch
```

"Batching" of messages might interact in complicated ways with bounded queues, though.  No free lunch.

Comment: Adding a message queue will result in more overhead of thread synchronization. If Thread 1 is writing message . thread 2 must wait for thread 1  is done even though the data needed by thread 2 has been available.

Comment: How about setting up a bool variable dataUpdateFlag. If the data has been updated, the read thread read buffer otherwise check other flags or wait for this one.

Comment: So you are going to spin-loop through all of the flags?  That might not very efficient, either.  I actually suspect the message queues will be about as fast as you can get.  If you have more threads than cores, while one thread is waiting on its queue another can make progress...  Net effect should be to keep all of the cores busy, which is the goal.

Comment: If you put all message in one queue, after one thread is finished with writing a message (unlock the mutex), how to wake up only the related message receiver without waking up all other unrelated receivers ? If all threads wait on the same mutex and the same condition variable, the data cannot be exchanged correctly.

Comment: I do not understand.  My proposal is to have one message queue _per thread_.  To send a message to a thread, you put it into that thread's queue and then signal the corresponding condition variable.  So there is only one "receiver" for each queue.  (For each queue, there are many producers, but only one consumer.)

Comment: Suppose that we have 2 threads. Thread 1 is responsible for the computing task node 1 and node 2. Thread 2 is responsible for the computing task node 3 and node 4. Node 1 needs to exchange data with node 3 and Node 2 needs to exchange data with node 4 and also Node 1 needs to exchange data with node 2 and Node 3 needs to exchange data with node 4.

Comment: In this way, we have inter-thread and intra-thread communication. After node 1 task is done, Thread 1 write a message to the message-queue with a mutex lock. Then, unlock the mutex. How to send the notification signal to the thread 2 ?

Comment: If we use the mutex to lock the whole message queue, there is only one notification signal associated with the mutex. If we have 3 or more threads (consumers) that need to check the message queue, all of them will be waken up.

Comment: Because in the problem, it is possible that a node "i" has a group of neighboring nodes so that all these neighboring nodes are consumers of the computing results of the node "i". Moreover, each neighboring node "j" is connected to the node "i" with a distinct arc that may cause the computing result from node "i" for node "j" to different from each other.

Comment: According to your idea, each arc needs to be associated with a message queue such that the two ending nodes of the arc can use the message queue to notify each other. Right ?

Comment: A data consumer is also a data producer because each node needs to tell its neighbors about its result and also needs to know the result of its neighbors .

Comment: I am suggesting you use a different mechanism for intra-thread and inter-thread communication.  Intra-thread you do not need any mutexes or condition variables.  Inter-thread, you use a _single_ message queue for _each_ thread.  (So no, in my proposal, each "arc" does _not_ have a message queue.  Each _thread_ has a message queue.)  So there is no locking between Node 1 and Node 2.  When Node 1 needs to write to Node 3, thread 1 locks the queue for thread 2 and inserts a "write this to Node 3" message.  The messages are _instructions_ to the thread that owns the queue.

Comment: My understanding about your idea: Node 1 locks the mutex for the message queue (thread 1 write node 1 data, thread 2 read node 1 data), and then notify thread 2 with a condition variable. But, one mutex can only be associated with one condition variable.

Comment: When node 2 data is available, thread 1 lock the same mutex and send the notification signal to thread 2. Thread 2 needs check the available data is from node 1 or node 2, right ? If the message queue is very long, it is not efficient because thread 2 needs to iterate the message queue from head to tail.

Comment: No, that is not my idea.  The individual nodes do not have mutexes...  The idea is to associate each queue with a _thread_, not with a _node_.  So when thread 1 reads node 1's data or writes node 2's data, it does not lock anything because it "owns" both of those nodes.  Only when thread 1 needs to write to node 3 does it grab a lock. And the lock it grabs is on _thread 2's message queue_.  Thread 1 just sends a message thread 2 saying "please write this to Node 3 for me".  (Only the thread owning a node can read/write directly to that node, and it does not need any locks to do so.)

Comment: or, you mean : the front element of the message queue is poped by thread 2 and then thread 2 use the poped message to find out where it sent from and where it is sent to ?

Comment: No need to iterate anything.  Within a thread, you just need to efficiently answer the query, "Give me a node all of whose inputs are ready".  A simple priority queue will work fine.  (For each node, keep track of how many inputs it is "waiting for".  When that number reaches zero, that node reaches the top of the priority queue.  You pop it off and compute its output.   Continue until you cannot proceed.  If output needs to go off-thread, send a message.  When you cannot proceed, block on your message queue and process it in one swoop.)

Comment: Yes, but you can pop all of the messages at once if you want so you can process them without one lock per message.  The idea is to separate the intra-thread and inter-thread mechanisms.  You should be able to operate very efficiently intra-thread with no locks at all.  Inter-thread you use message queues.  That's it.

Comment: Thread 1 (hold node 1, 2) is associated with priority message Q1; Thread 2 (hold node 3 , 4) is associated with priority message Q2; Thread 1 pushes node 1 and 2 into Q1, Thread 1 pushes node 3 and 4 into Q2. Whenever a node's computing is done, its priority is set to be highest so that it can be poped at first. Meanwhile, the thread that hold the queue send a notification with condition variable so that the waiting thread is waken up to pop the front from the ready Q. For example, thread 1 notifies thread 2 if node 1 is ready for pop by lock the mutex of Q1 and send condition signal.

Comment: Thread 2 waiting for the signal will be waken up and pop Q1 to get its front element, which is used for its local computing task. The same things go for thread 2. Right ? I think each thread's message Q should be able to be accessed by all related threads that hold some nodes with connection arcs with some nodes in the queue. For example, if node 1 also has an arc with node 5 that is held by thread 3, the thread 1's Q should also be shared with thread 3. Or, node 1 has arcs with node 5 held by thread 3. So, Q1 should be able to be accessed by thread 1 , 2 and 3. right ?